# Parsing file with RegEx for multiple line matches with capture groups

Tags: linux, regex, grep

I have some files. I want to match the following string from each file, which is on two lines.

```
<TagA>A7C</TagA>
    <!--<TagA>70458548767</TagA>-->
```

However, I want grep or pcregrep or whatever Linux utility to display:

```
A7C 767
```

Note: The first 8 digits of the number on the second line can be considered random.  For my purposes that are just to be dropped no matter their value.  Also the second line has leading white space.

GC_

Comment: Does `grep -oP '\w{3}(?=</TagA>)' filename` do what you want?  [Requires GNU grep.  Don't try this on a Mac.]

Comment: That actually kind of works...  However, the results are not on one line together. It is clearly not matching only my results.  However, I'm not sure it matters in my case.

Comment: @John1024 Is there some easy way to pull both results onto one line?  Otherwise, I can probably just macros in notepad++.

Comment: You said you're using Notepad++, what about: Find:`.*(\w{3})</TagA>.*\R?`, Replace with: `$1 `<-- there is a space after `$1`

Comment: Does this two-line pattern appear only once in each file, or might it appear multiple times (e.g., lines 16&17, and again at lines 42&43) in the same file — and, if it appears multiple times in a file, do you want to get all occurrences (or just the first, or just the last)? Must the solution match only patterns exactly like the example, or are you just concerned with `<TagA>` … `</TagA>` pairs on two consecutive lines? (For example, can we have `foo<TagA>A7C</TagA>bar` or `<TagA>A7C20Q</TagA>`?) Can you say anything about the size of the files? (E.g., are they probably under 1000 bytes each?)

Comment: @Scott It does only appear once in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The separate out the numbers that you want:

```
$ grep -oP '\w{3}(?=</TagA>)' input
A7C
767
```

In the above, `\w{3}` matches any three word characters and `(?=</TagA>)` requires that that match precede `</TagA>`.  Normally, grep prints the whole line containing a match.  `-o` tells grep instead to print only the match.  `-P` tells grep to use Perl-syntax which is necessary to enable the look-ahead feature `(?=</TagA>)`.

To get both numbers on one line:

```
$ grep -oP '\w{3}(?=</TagA>)' input | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
A7C 767
```

Comment: I like your answer.  However, I will leave the question open in case anyone comes up with a RegEx that will only match my intended strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl way that works for any number of occurrences:

```
perl -ane 'print "$& " if m~\w{3}(?=</TagA>)~' file
```

**Explanation:**

```
print "$& "             # print the match with a space after
if m~\w{3}(?=</TagA>)~  # match 3 word characters before end tag </TagA>
```

**Sample file:**

```
blah
<TagA>A7C</TagA>
    <!--<TagA>70458548767</TagA>-->
blah blah
<TagB>A7C</TagB>
    <!--<TagA>70458548767</TagA>-->
blah blah
<TagA>A7C</TagA>
    <!--<TagC>70458548767</TagC>-->
blah blah
```

**Output:**

```
A7C 767 767 A7C
```